# Bash on windows python can't connect to PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Pycharm has been correctly configured and python scripts can be run normally throught it, but when the debug function is used, after some time this message shows up.

```
ssh://mike@127.0.0.1:22/home/mike/anaconda3/bin/python3.6 -u /home/mike/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 55439 --file /mnt/c/Users/mt/PycharmProjects/..***../mlp.py
Could not connect to 0.0.0.0: 55439
NoneType: None

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Before running the cython speedups the message was a bit more verbose with an exception.

```
ssh://mike@127.0.0.1:22/home/mike/anaconda2/bin/python2.7 -u /home/mike/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 55730 --file /mnt/c/Users/mt/PycharmProjects/...***.../labeling.py
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/home/mike/anaconda2/bin/python2.7" "/home/mike/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
Could not connect to 0.0.0.0: 55730
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 527, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/home/mike/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does bash on windows need some kind of configuration to communicate with windows through the adress 0.0.0.0?

(Not using insider build)